# Why only human have noticeable difference in face?

Tags: genetics, dna, crossover

Our facial appearance is pretty much different from each other unless we are talking about twin. Credit goes to crossing over of chromosome. But why can't we distinguish between other animals of same species? Yes there are some very little differences but not that much clear and obvious difference like we have. Why is that?

Comment: So it's because we are human. Therefore  we can distinguish between two human easily?